# Use the content before the <!--more--> in such case

Tags: wordpress

I would like to echo the content before the `<!--more-->`-Tag instead of cutting the content after 250 characters. The Theme do not use the `the_content`.

```
    $content_of_post = get_post($get_post_id);
    $content = $content_of_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
    echo substr($content, 0, "250");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate your text till `<!--more-->` by strpos function, i.e:

```
substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '<!--more-->'));
```

Try this:

```
<?php
$content_of_post = get_post($get_post_id);
$content = $content_of_post->post_content;
$content = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '<!--more-->'));
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
?>
```